# How to refetch query after subscription triggered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I am maintaining a subscription **AddTaskSubscription** in my application. It is working as expected, I was able to see the data.

```
  const { data } = useSubscription(AddTaskSubscription, {
    onSubscriptionComplete: () => { },
    onSubscriptionData: () => {
      console.log('data');
    },
  });
```

I wanted to refetch a query whenever subscription successfully returns the data.

I seed `refetchQueries` in useMutation. Do we have any kind of help with **useSubscription** or is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: writeQuery in onSubscriptionData ...  queries related to cache changed data should be refreshed without calliing refetch

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a loop function that runs every time there is data, so I look it up for looping in jsx and I found this.

```
var rows = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numrows; i++) {
    // note: we add a key prop here to allow react to uniquely identify each
    // element in this array. see: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html
    rows.push(<ObjectRow key={i} />);
}
return <tbody>{rows}</tbody>;
```

and if I want to try to connect it to your code maybe it is something like this.

```
const index = ({ data }) => {

   let  subsData = []
    const [onSubscriptionData, setOnSubscriptionData] = useState({ });
    useSubscription(AddTaskSubscription, {
        onSubscriptionComplete: () => { },
        onSubscriptionData: () => {
            console.log('data');
            setOnSubscriptionData({ data })
        },
    })
    for (var i = 0; i < onSubscriptionData; i++) {
        subsData.push(<Data key={i} />);
    }
    return(
        <div>
            {subsData}
        </div>
    )
}
```

I don't know if it's working or not because I can't test it.